# Why am I getting these errors in my assembly code (Option casemap: none)?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I'm writing assembly code with the [GUI Turbo Assembler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/guitasm8086/) (a Turbo Assembler GUI environment for Windows that produces DOS programs that run in DOSBox). When I run the program the assembler gives this error:

> x.asm Error x.asm(**3**) Illegal instruction

Line 3 is `option casemap: none`. My code is:

```
.586                                  
.model flat,stdcall ;           
option casemap:none ; Line that is giving an error             
.DATA               ;              
x db 2             ;           
y db 1          
z db 1        
 .data?           
 a db ?       ;           
 b db ?       ; b=2             
 c db ?       ; c=2              
 d db ?       ; d=2                  
 e db ?       ; e=23,5               
 f db ?       ; f=4                   
 g db ?       ; g=-18,5                              
 .code       ;                                                    
 beg:        ;                                                

 mov  ah,x  ; AH:=x                 
 mov  bh,z  ; BH:=z                        
 imul bh    ; AH:=xz:=2                  
mov  b,ah  ; b:=2                          

mov  ah,x   ; AH:=x                      
mov  ch,y   ; CH:=y                   
idiv ch    ; AH:=AH/CH:=x/y:=2                  
mov  ch,ah ; CH:=2                 
mov  c,ch  ; c=2          

mov  ah,y   ; AH:=y                      
mul  ah     ; AH=1^2=1                     
mov  bh,z  ; BH:=z                    
imul bh    ; AH:=yz:=1                 
mov  ch,x  ;  CH=x                  
imul ch    ; AH=AHCH=1x=2                              
mov  d,ah ; d=2                                      

mov AH,45 ; AH=45                      
mov BH, d ; BH=2               
idiv BH   ; AH=45/2=22,5                  
mov e, AH ; e=22,5              

mov ah,b  ; AH=b                            
mov ch,c  ; CH=c                 
add ah,ch; AH=b+c=2+2=4               
mov f, ah; AH=f               

mov ah,f  ; AH=f                   
mov ch, e ; CH=e                    
sub ah,ch; AH=4-22,5=-18,5                   
mov g,ah  ; g=-18,5             

mov ah,g  ; AH=g             
mov ch,5  ; CH=5                 
sub ah,ch; AH=-18,5-5=-23,5               

mov a,ah  ; a=AH=-23,5                                     

end beg
```

Comment: Should be a `.` before `option`? (just guessing)

Comment: @Eraklon : no, in MASM and TASM syntax `option` is a directive that isn't preceded by a `:`

Comment: @Michael Petch I try to write (.data) , but it doesn't help, maybe you know another problem?)

Comment: @Michael Petch I delet it and try run, but also have error  assembling                
         file:   x.asm
 Error messages:    None       
 Warning messages:  None           
 Passes:            1             
 Remaining memory:  467k      
Building executable from - C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\x.obj, using switch : '/3 /x /v'                 
 Turbo Link  Version 7.1.30.1. Copyright (c) 1987, 1996 Borland International                                     
Fatal: Bad object file record in module X.ASM near module file offset 0x0000013E

Comment: @Michael Petch assembling                
         file:   x.asm
 Error messages:    None       
 Warning messages:  None           
 Passes:            1             
 Remaining memory:  467k      
Building executable from - C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\x.obj, using switch : '/3 /x /v'                 
 Turbo Link  Version 7.1.30.1. Copyright (c) 1987, 1996 Borland International                                     
Fatal: Bad object file record in module X.ASM near module file offset 0x0000013E   Something like this

Comment: @Michael Petch I do not know what i can do. I read all posts about assembly, but can not solve this problem

Comment: I'd be curious why you want to write DOS programs. Is that a requirement? If you wanted to write Windows programs you could download the free [MS Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) which comes with a GUI, and Microsoft assembler that can target Windows 32 and Windows 64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OPTION` keyword wasn't introduced until TASM 5 according to the [change logs](http://bytepointer.com/tasm/index.htm). GUI Turbo Assembler currently uses TASM 4.1. You don't need the `OPTION CASEMAP` feature since your code uses all the same case for the labels in your code. The fix is to remove:

```
option casemap:none
```

Since GUI Turbo Assembler targets running DOS programs you will need to change:

```
.model flat,stdcall
```

to something like:

```
.model small,stdcall
```

In DOS the memory models can be `small`. `medium`, `compact`, `large`, and `huge` . `flat` doesn't apply to DOS programs. Using `flat` will result in a linker error under the GUI Turbo Assembler environment.

For DOS you will also want to add a stack and specify its size. Something like this should work:

```
.stack 256          ; Set stack size to 256 bytes
```

Comment: Thank you very much ))